# Explicit data type declaration of mutual class references disabled intellisense

Tags: python, reference, intellisense, declaration, python-typing

I would like to know how to solve this problem:

This throws error (GUI is not known at the point of processing `gui : GUI`):

```
class AppLogic():
    
    gui : GUI

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.gui = None

    def image_clicked(self):
        pass #not important
    
class GUI():

    app_logic : AppLogic
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.app_logic = None
        
    def render_image(self):
        pass #not important

app = AppLogic()
gui = GUI()

app.gui = gui
gui.app_logic = app
```

I can delete the explicit data type declaration, but at that moment, I will lose all the intellisense power when I would like to use hints while using the attribute `gui` or `app_logic` inside the class definition. Does it have any solution to make intellisense working in this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class)

Comment: `GUI` is the wrong type if `self.gui = None` should be allowed.

Comment: It should probably be `gui: Optional['GUI']`, so that you can create the `AppLogic`, define `GUI` with the existing `AppLogic` instance as an argument so that you can initialize the `app_logic` attribute *immediately*, then assign `app.gui = gui` afterwards. (It's not possible to define the two objects with references to each other simultaneously.)

Comment: (It seems to make more sense to have an application with no GUI than a GUI that's not associated with an application.)

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, thats it. Forward references. Saved my day. :) Thanks

Comment: @chepner I don't know what do you mean by not having GUI associated with application. I am learning PyQt on my own, and I have never seen any common GUI app achitectures (I am C embedded SW engineer :) ). But I am interested in this architecture topic, but don't know where to start. Do you have some tips? :)

Comment: I mean, you could have a command-line application that has no GUI, but it's much less useful to have a GUI that isn't an interface to any particular application.

Comment: And why do you think think the GUI will work badly? I just wanted to seperate rendering of different GUI blocks from the app logic. Is that bad idea?